# Kotlin global functions not converted to Swift with KMP

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, generate

I'm working on a Kotlin Multiplatform project where I have some Kotlin functions that are not within a class. According to the documentation, these functions should be directly converted to Swift functions accessible from Swift code. However, I'm encountering an issue where these functions are not being converted, would you help me, are there some steps to generate them.

Answer (score 3):

KMP generates ObjC headers, and since ObjC has no global functions, Kotlin generates a class that contains a static function.

From Swift you can call it like `FileNameKt.globalFunction` if your `globalFunction` is placed inside `FileName.kt`.

In such cases, when you don't know what the generated version looks like in Swift, it is useful to take a look at the generated headers, where you can search for the needed name. You can find it in `shared.framework/Headers/shared.h` where `shared` is the name of your KMP framework - I prefer to add it to Xcode source files without adding to any target for easy access.

Comment: But FileNameKt class is not generating. do you know why it is not generating, do I need to add something in gradle to generate it?

Comment: @ShubhamMogarkar is this function in shared module, or in an other one? have you tried looking for it in `shared.h`?

Comment: @ShubhamMogarkar `shared.h` was not generated at all? other functions work fine? Can you add a new class and create it from iOS part? make sure your gradle script runs successfully

Comment: problem was that I was not writing the import statement to import shared files and Xcode was not showing suggestions to write import statement like Android Studio suggests.